# Keeping local Timezone information from an ISO 8601, RFC3339 formatted dates in iOS

Tags: swift, date

I know there are tons of post regarding iso8601 strings and timezones but I could not find anything that really pinpoints the problem I had recently.

I have an ISO 8601 RFC3339 formatted string like: `2021-03-31T12:00:00+03:00`.

I want to display the time associated with this date in the **local time** of the provided date meaning I want exactly "12:00" as the output. If my formatter has `dateFormat` of `HH:mm`

If I use an `ISO8601DateFormatter` to extract the date everything seems to work fine and the associated `Date` object is `2021-03-31 09:00:00 +0000`. Which makes sense since `12:00GMT+3 = 09:00GMT+0`

However this completely removes `Timezone` information from the Date object (which I know is by design on iOS).

While I understand the design behind this (most of the time we eventually should display the time in the user device timezone). There are quite a few exceptions like travel applications where we almost alway want to display the local time of departure/arrival.

My solution was to store the json serialized dates as `Strings` and use a combination of `ISO8601DateFormatter` to create the `Date` object in UTC and a normal `DateFormatter` that reconstructs the TZ from the `+03:00` substring.

What's the best approach to solve this ?

Comment: The tool you want here is DateComponents, rather than Date. Unfortunately I don't see any way to convert a String into DateComponents in Foundation. The tool I've typically used is https://github.com/soffes/ISO8601. DateComponents is almost always the right way to keep track of "human-facing" dates, because it represents what people think of when they say "date."

Comment: BTW, how are you using a DateFormatter to reconstruct the TimeZone from "+03:00"?

Comment: The OP's goal isn't to print a Date. It's to display "12:00" given a ISO8601 string, which is a critical function for travel applications. That's why the right tool here is DateComponents. Do note that tracking the time zone  as `+03:00` is also going to cause you trouble if this is a travel app. Time zone laws change often, so a location that was +3 on a certain future date may be in some other time zone by the time that date comes around. It at all possible, store the city/region rather than a fixed UTC offset.

Comment: (I originally taught myself Objective-C in order to write a personal Mac app to keep track of my travel back when I was flying all over the world. Correctly dealing with airport time zones is so much harder than it sounds. :D)

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for your feedback to answer your question since I store the seralialized strings I wrote a simple extension on `Timezone` that inits itself with a rfc3339 string like "+03:00" and redirects its init call with the corresponding secondsFromUTC. Then I can just set myFormatter.timeZone = Timezone(rfc3339String: myString). Technically my words were misleading, the formatter doesn't do anything, the trick lies within the Timezone initializer.